# Countinuous processing of tail -f output

Tags: bash, tail

I have a file where numbers are continuously appended:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want to calculate their mean, also continuously, i.e.:

```
1
1.5
2
2,5
```

I don't want to check file periodically, I want to it in the manner tail -f work - as soon as a line is appended, I perform mean calculations.

Is it possible?

**UPD** Question moved to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400306/countinuous-processing-of-tail-f-output

Comment: Wait, how did you get a mean of 5?

Comment: tip: have a look at the `tailf` man :)

Comment: Is it possible YES!

Comment: >>Wait, how did you get a mean of 5;
true. Screwed up

Comment: I am not aware of any tools to do this for you, but I know this should be trivial to do with a perl script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Pipe `tail -f` to a script that handles your averaging. The pipe will never close and the script can process instantly for each line it receives... it will block until a line appears.

Also, one should keep in mind that it is possible to calculate a running average without having to add all the values each time. I've seen it that enough I feel the need to mention it.

```
#generator.pl
$| = 1; #immediate flush
while (1) {
    print int rand(100), "\n";
    sleep 1;
}
```

---

```
#average.pl
$| = 1; #immediate output flush
my $average = 0;
my $count = 0;
while (<>) {
    $average = ($average * $count + $_) / ($count + 1);
    $count++;
    print $average, "\n";
}
```

---

```
$ perl generator.pl > source &
[2] 15564
(reverse-i-search)`': ^C
$ tail -f source | perl average.pl
54
28
27.6666666666667
35
41
```

And, just for grins:

```
$tail -f source | awk '{total+=$0; count+=1; print total/count}'
```

That also has instant feedback. It seems to me that your issue is buffering by the application that is writing to the file that tail is reading from.

See http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/ for info on that.

Comment: I have tried to do it with awk, but it didn't work, i.e. tail -f file.txt | awk {total+=$0; count+=1} END {print total/count} - and it just doesn't give any output

Comment: @Stas ... as it shouldn't because you put that in the END block. Since the file never ends, it never prints. `awk {total+=$0; count+=1; print total/count}`

Comment: Yep, tried, but still hangs...

Comment: The source is actually apache's access log. Probably I can't influence it's flushing... But I mean, if I can see it on the screen line by line, it must be a way to process it accordingly. Thanks for perl script. I will save them for exceptional case

Comment: ok, I have figured out what was wrong. I used another awk after tail -f, which was buffered. Should be like tail -f source.txt | awk '{print $0; fflush()}' | awk '{total....}'. But thanks for your help - it did help a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution using dc.

`tail -f  | dc -e '5k 0 d sc st [? lc 1 + sc lt + st lt lc / p c lax] sa lax'`

I'm not sure whether dc supports tail recursion, if not this program will leak memory. dc has really bad documentation. :)

What, you don't like brainfuck? :)

Here's an easy solution in Ruby.
`tail -f  | ruby -e 'sum=total=0.0; while line=gets; total += line.to_f; sum += 1; puts total/sum; end'`